# Select a column based on another column's value in Spark Dataframe using Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 5 columns - `sourceId`, `score_1`, `score_3`, `score_4` and `score_7`. The values of `sourceId` column can be `[1, 3, 4, 7]`. I want to convert this into another dataframe that has the columns `sourceId` and `score`, where score depends on the value of the `sourceId` column.

| sourceId | score_1 | score_3 | score_4 | score_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.45 | 0.21 |
| 4 | 0.15 | 0.66 | 0.73 | 0.47 |
| 7 | 0.34 | 0.41 | 0.78 | 0.16 |
| 3 | 0.77 | 0.1 | 0.93 | 0.67 |

So if `sourceId = 1`, we select value of `score_1` for that record, if `sourceId = 3`, we select value of `score_3`, and so on...

Result would be

| sourceId | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 4 | 0.73 |
| 7 | 0.16 |
| 3 | 0.1 |

What would be the best way to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining multiple `when` expressions on `id` column values:

```scala
val ids = Seq(1, 3, 4, 7)

val scoreCol = ids.foldLeft(lit(null)) { case (acc, id) =>
  when(col("sourceId")===id, col(s"score_$id")).otherwise(acc)
}

val df2 = df.withColumn("score", scoreCol)
```

---

Or building a map expression from `score_*` columns and use it to get `score` values:

```scala
val scoreMap = map(
  df.columns
    .filter(_.startsWith("score_"))
    .flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c.split("_")(1)), col(c))): _*
)

val df2 = df.withColumn("score", scoreMap(col("sourceId")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to create a dynamic `when` condition:

```java
ArrayList<String> scoresCols = {"score_1", "score_2", ...};
Column actualScoreCol = when(col("sourceId")
  .equalTo(scoresCols.get(0)), col(scoresCols.get(0))
  .cast("string")); // Can add "score_" as suffix and then compare

for (int i = 1; i < scoresCols.size(); i++) {
  actualScoreCol = actualScoreCol
    .when(col("sourceId")
    .equalTo(scoresCols.get(i)), col(scoresCols.get(i))
    .cast("string"));
}
ds = joinedDataset.withColumn("actual", actualCol);
```